# Efficient, elegant way to create mathematical series in Python

Tags: javascript, python

In Javascript, here is a simple mathematical series.

```
var myList = []

for (var x = 2; x < 10000; x = x * 2) {
    mylist.push(x);
}
```

---

I cannot create a similar series in **Python** without:

- Using a while loop
- Looping over the entire range of numbers to 10,000 in a comprehension

*Is this one of the rare cases where Python is a less elegant language?*
*Am I unaware of some functionality in Python here?*

Comment: I would remove the question about elegance. It's opinion-based and therefore off-topic here.

Comment: Isn't this done simply with `map(lambda x: x*2, range(2,10000))`?

Comment: @Abdou Nope, the generated series is `[2, 4, 8, 16...]`.

Comment: I don't know Python, but I know it has a lot of features of functional programming. In Haskell the code would be `myList = takeWhile (<10000) (iterate (*2) 2)`, so surely there's a Python translation.

Comment: If you don't want to loop over every value at once, you could use a generator expression and get values as needed: `gen = (2 ** n for n in range(1, 10001))`.

Comment: @JohanL so... replace `x*2` with `2**(x-1)`?

Comment: "Is this one of the rare cases where Python is a less elegant language?" what? This JS is using a `for` loop itself.

Comment: `[2**n for n in xrange(1,int(math.ceil(math.log(10000,2))))]`?

Comment: @ChristianDean I think the OP wants the series to stop at 10,000 not have a length of 10,000, which means it would be `range(1, 14)`

Comment: @4castle Yeah your right. I just noticed.

Comment: Stopping at 14 is as simple as taking the log of whatever he wants to stop at.

Comment: @JohanL, I see now. `itertools.accumulate` should do this with `math.log(10000, 2)`. Something like: `itertools.accumulate([2]*int(math.log(10000,2)), int.__mul__)`. But still sort of uglier than a `while-loop` to my taste.

Comment: @Abdou I believe you meant *still* instead *style*.

Comment: @ChristianDean, yup. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with itertools (as suggested by 4castle) operating on generator expressions.

```
from itertools import takewhile, count
myList = takewhile(lambda x: x < 10000, map(lambda x: 2 ** x, count()))
```

In python 2, you will need to use `itertools.imap` instead of `map`.

Comment: Note that you'll have to cast `myList` if you want a _list_ of values via `list()`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the question here. What do you class as elegance? For a couple of (perfectly legible) extra you can have a `while` loop set up.

```
def my_func():
    x = 2
    my_list = []

    while x < 10000:
        my_list.append(x)
        x = x * 2
```

I used `timeit` on an ancient laptop for basic code:

`10000000 loops, best of 3: 34.9 ns per loop`

This debate is irrelevant in terms of execution time or readability. There is no merit in discussing this further than to get into a debate about `{}` and `;` that are all over JS in general, which is counter-productive. I'm sure some people are looking for one-liners but that will be obfuscated and inefficient.

Comment: I'd tend to agree with you here. I don't see how the `while` loop in Python is that much less elegant than the `for` loop in JS.

Comment: @ChristianDean I found an interest in the fact that it wasn't so easy to do in Python (by the tiniest of margins) but I'd probably wager that the JS approach is slower anyway and the question only really incites a pointless language debate.

Answer (score 0):

"Efficient" and "elegant" can be a bit ambiguous. I'll assume "efficient" means both concise to type and quick to evaluate. And elegant I suppose means the result of its evaluation can be quickly and easily understood from the source.

Your question, in general, is difficult to answer because, for the most part, mathematical series as written by mathematicians can include arbitrarily complex operations that may or may not resolve to something "elegant" in one language or another (e.g. linear algebra is much more elegant in MATLAB/Octave than in Python).

Your question, specifically, is very easy to express elegantly (in either language) by noting the actual underlying mathematical expression you're really trying to evaluate:

[image]

Which, in python, is this:

```
from math import floor, log2
[2**x for x in range(1, floor(log2(10000))+1)]
```

In fact, I'm not sure you can represent the construction of this set as elegantly with JavaScript, but don't quote me on that because I am by no means an expert in that language.

So the answer is... It really depends on what you're trying to express. In this case, I prefer the python list comprehension to evaluation in a loop (in either language), but that's just me.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.